# Implementing of class with <T>

Tags: c#

I want to implement like this:

```
namespace PIMP.Web.TestForum.Models
{
    public class ThreadModel : PagedList<T>
    {
```

but I am getting ErrorMessage:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What should I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
namespace PIMP.Web.TestForum.Models
{
    public class ThreadModel<T> : PagedList<T>
    {
```

or change `T` to an actual type.

Comment: hey TIMWI, 
what i am asking wrong, that you always giving mne a minus points??